# How to create Copy of Clone Database for N Number of Clients in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to create copy of clone database for N Number of clients dynamically in sql.

The requirement is as below.

i am having a super admin database which is specific for super admin role alone and if any new client comes the super admin will get those client information and saves it.

During the Save process i need to create a copy of database for the client with the client information provided.

As same continues for N number of clients..

How to workout this logic dynamically with the existing tables.

Comment: why you need create new database while want to add new client? for what purpose?

Comment: Most likely to have distinct databases for each client. Depending on the type of application, type of client, type of scenario, this is not that uncommon or unwarranted.

Comment: Have you considered simply backing up the database and restoring it under a new name? Depending on the scenario you might have to rebuild access level control configuration to only allow the new client access.

Comment: Just We are integrating the source.There is no way to proceed with single database.So there is no other option..which will be effective restoring the backup database or creating the database and tables dynamically?

Comment: Do you need to keep the data as well or just the structure (tables, procedures, indexes etc`)?

Comment: Just the Structure..

Comment: Is there is an SQL Script to create the tables? Is there a backup file of an empty database? ...

Comment: Yeah Stefan Steinegger..Is it possible?..if So then How the Server performance will be?..Is adding database dynamically is a fair on any environment?.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Visual Studio SSDT (SQL Server) project - you can use visual studio express if you do not have visual studio already.

Import your table schema and if you have any reference data add it to a post deploy script.

Build the project and you will have a .dacpac.

When you want a new database, from a command prompt do:

```
sqlpackage.exe /Action:publish /sourcefile:path\to\dacpac.dacpac /TargetServerName:Server /TargetDatabaseName:%NEWDATABASENAME%
```

You can wrap the call to sqlpackage.exe in a batch or powershell script to make it simpler.

If you want to do it from a .net program you can call thed DacFx api directly (http://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/deploying-a-dacpac-with-dacfx-api/)

Good luck!

Ed